# Hiding pages and displaying first five pages in pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

I am doing a pagination with angularjs . My design is to show the first 5 pages initially when I click the 5th page I need to show the remaining pages with the 5th page first position and so on.

Could anyone suggest me how to implement the design?

Here is my working sample [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cR7ADJ3bQXpZ6aRBiIyV?p=preview) but I am unable to achieve the design which I wanted. Right now it has 16 pages. I am trying to show first 5 pages and then when I click the 5th page link the remaining next four pages including 5th page at the first position should be appear.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Here is my code link http://plnkr.co/edit/cR7ADJ3bQXpZ6aRBiIyV?p=preview

Comment: Is that how you are working with your code? Bootstrap doesn't load, no CSS loads. `:/`

Comment: My question is I need to show 5 pages and hide the remaining pages. When I click the 5th page and when I click the next button and if it reach to 5th page I should hide the 1, 2, 3, 4 pages and display 5, 6 ,7 , 8, 9 .. same thing applies when you click 9th page link Every time I need to show 5 pages. Right now my code is showing all the pages..

Comment: you really need to create your own pagination? Angular is really bind to bootstrap

Comment: I made it happen the way that I want thanks for the suggestion everyone here is the updated code link http://plnkr.co/edit/SEx3NRum7fRMcYsu8ymT?p=preview  my only problem is initially when I click 5 it loads next pages as usually like this 5 6 7 8 9 and when I click 5 it should go back and show 1 2 3 4 5 any suggestions for that??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap pagination (i think you do) set boundery-links to true and max-size to 5, pagination will show 5 pages, on 5 page click it will add 2 more.

```
<pagination 
 boundary-links="true" 
 max-size="5" 
 items-per-page="10" 
 total-items="100" 
 ng-model="currentPage" 
 ng-change="pageChanged()">
</pagination>
```

Comment: Pagination is working fine with my thanks for the suggestion but I made it customize, here is the updated code link plnkr.co/edit/SEx3NRum7fRMcYsu8ymT?p=preview my only problem is initially when I click 5 it loads next pages as usual like this 5 6 7 8 9 and when I click 5 it should go back and show 1 2 3 4 5 any suggestions for that??